# Android Instrumentation Orchestrator's `clearPackageData` does not clear data

Tags: android, android-instrumentation, android-test-orchestrator

I have defined these into my `build.gradle`, to enable Orchestrator in my Android Instrumented tests:

```
defaultConfig {
 testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'
}

testOptions {
  animationsDisabled = true
  execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
}

dependencies {
 androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.5.1'
 androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.4.2'
}
```

Sadly, when I start tests, data is not cleared and it persists between test runs.

I tried both, start test from Android Studio and by gradle cli `./gradlew connectedStageDebugAndroidTest`

Any idea what I am doing wrong?